# Своя библиотека для android

Tags: java, android, sdk

Есть бекенд, собой представляет чат между двумя пользователями с возможностью видео конференции между пользователями.
Стоит задача написать библиотеку для android, чтобы упростить написание приложения под этот бекенд.
Вопросы:
С  чего начинать?
Какую архитектуру сделать, чтобы компоненты были не сильно связаны между собой и были легко заменимы?
Можно ли использовать сторонние библиотеки, такие как retrofit, android annotation и т.д.?

Comment: сторонние библиотеки конечно можно использовать, почему нет.

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо, а как на счет других вопросов?